# JS and jQuery - loop through textboxes and store value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the function that checks if the form is complete.

So, what I'm trying to do:

1. If radio is not selected, throw a message.
2. If radio is "yes", but text is not entered, throw error.
3. If radio is "no" but text is entered, make the text empty.
4. If all is good, add stuff into `allResponses

The form was displayed 5 times, and input was as follows:

```
Yes a1

No

Yes a3

No

Yes
```

Now, this input should display an error since in 5th case, "yes" is selected but nothing is entered in the textbox.

However, I get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXMDl.png

Also, the text is not being updated as in 1st and 3rd cases.

I don't know a lot about JS, so please provide me with as explained responses as you can.

EDIT: Complete code: http://pastebin.com/scNSNM2H

Thanks

Comment: place snipplets to the question. make fiddle if you can, narrow your problem, add sample html markup

Comment: what is `data["itemIndex"]` ?

Comment: Just a data structure that hold all values.. `data` is defined as follows: `data = {"itemIndex":-1,"responses":[]}`

Comment: **narrow your problem** this is pretty easy make thing you asking for, but it is pretty hard to understand *what is your form is*, *what is that out of scope variables*

Comment: OMG, **html markup form** please.... I bet fiddle will be hard for you

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring it out. If you can provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ page with the problem occurring, it'd be a lot easier to figure out what's going on and help you with it.

Comment: Please see OP. I have sample input, expected output and output that is showing up actually. I don't know how else I can narrow the problem. Would it help if I post the complete html file?

Comment: Yes - it would help if you post the complete html file.

Comment: @eicto Posted it: http://pastebin.com/scNSNM2H

Comment: ok, what is indexIntotips.js and jokes.js ? make this http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/svvge/ work, than back

Comment: jokes.js is an array of strings. indexIntotips.js contains just this
`var indexesIntoTips = [[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9]]`. Not sure what to do with the fiddle..

Comment: add here sample data from jokes.js and indexesIntoTips

Comment: done! Shows correct but doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this in a loop:

```
var exaggerationPart = document.getElementById('exaggeration').value
```

And then you check to make sure it has a value for each item.  But you will get the same value each time.

You are creating multiple inputs with the same id, "exaggeration".  This is invalid HTML.  Id's must be unique.  To correct this, you can increment the id the same as you are doing with other elements (such as, `input[name='response"+thisJokeIndex+"']`).

```
var exaggerationPart = document.getElementById('exaggeration' + thisJokeIndex).value
```

```
tipTD2.append("<input type='text' name='exaggeration' id='exaggeration" + tipIndex + "' size='70'>")
```

**Working demo:** [jsfiddle.net/svvge/2](http://jsfiddle.net/svvge/2/)

**Edit:** To clear the value of the text box, you must change the `value` property of the text box element.  Right now you are just changing the value of a variable.

```
var exaggerationInput = document.getElementById('exaggeration' + thisJokeIndex).value;
var exaggerationPart = exaggerationInput.value;
```

```
exaggerationInput.value = '';
```

Comment: Why will I get same value everytime? If I'm looping, shouldn't the values be looped as well? Ans how can I fix it then?

Comment: @KaranGoel - Why *would* it change?  There is nothing special about a `for` loop that would cause `document.getElementById('exaggeration')` to return a different element in subsequent loop iterations.  `document.getElementById` will *always* return the first element with a matching `id`.

Comment: Oh yes, makes sense. But then when I make `exaggerationPart` empty (if "no" radio is selected) then why does it still contain the text that was added in first textbox? Like in the example in OP.

Comment: Because `exaggerationPart` is a variable containing a string.  You've changed the value of the variable only.  To change the `value` property of the element, you must get a reference to the element and assign the value to the property.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I don't get it. `exaggerationPart ` contains the `value` of the text field. So I make `exaggerationPart` empty, and then adding it to the array, why won't the change be reflected?

Comment: `exaggerationPart` is a *string variable*.  You copied the string contained in your input element into that variable.  The variable is *not* a reference to the property.  It's just a string variable.  See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Y98PD/).  Did you expect `a` and `b` to both equal `2`?